# Semantic UI double the width of a field in a fields div

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I am using Semantic UI.

and here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fa257gw6/) (You need to stretch the Result panel to see the issue)

```
<div class="ui form segment">
    <div class="three fields">
        <div class="field">
            <label>Field One</label>
            <input></input>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Field Two</label>
            <input></input>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Field Three</label>
            <input></input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="three fields">
        <div class="field">
            <label>Field One</label>
            <input></input>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Field Two**</label>
            <input></input>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make "Field Two**" in the second row stretch to the end of "Field Three"

Answer (score 0):

here an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/step/mn8yjspv/)

```
<div class="ui form segment">
  <div class="three fields">
      <div class="field">
          <label>Field One</label>
          <input></input>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
          <label>Field Two</label>
          <input></input>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
          <label>Field Three</label>
          <input></input>
      </div>
   </div>
  <div class="three fields">
      <div class="field">
          <label>Field One</label>
          <input></input>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
      </div>
      <div class="field">
          <label>Field Two**</label>
          <input></input>
      </div>        
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope it is the result you want

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm looking to double the width of the field. It will start at the same place, but the input field will stretch to the end of "Field Three"